# Converting dictionary from .txt file to C# variable

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, txt

I need help with converting a dictionary from some `.txt` file to a variable in C#. Take a look at this picture below (the `.txt` file):

[image: The txt file]

As you can see, there is a dictionary in which are other two dictionaries. I want to ask if it is possible to convert it to an actual C# dictionary. Now, the `.txt` file does not correspond to C# obviously, because I just don't know how to do that or if it is even possible.

I have this code below to just open the file and read it line by line:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class MapLoader: MonoBehaviour
{
   void Start()
   {
       string mapID = "SGT589H";

       string path = $"Maps/{mapID}.txt";

       Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();

       using (var file = new StreamReader(path))
       {
           string line = null;

           bool skip = false;

           while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
           { 
               ........
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Don't mind the Unity Engine, it doesn't matter in my question. So my goal is to take the dictionary from the `.txt` file and save it in the C# dictionary named "map" so I can work with the dictionary later (it will be generating maps based on the data, I will be saving them as `.txt` files, not as unity scenes, to save space and then use my MapHandler to load them). As you can see, the `<string, string>` doesn't correspond too.

My question is, is there any way how to achieve that or could you possibly give me some ideas on how I would be able to change the structure to be able to do that? Thank you.

Comment: @user9938 just that what the file contains is _not_ JSON.

Comment: We're i you, I would turn that file into json with a couple of string Replace operations and proceed from there. No point reinventing Newtonsoft for the sake of a couple of colons and a double quoted identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide to take path of interpreting this json-like format yourself you need to write serializer to convert Python structures into C# which can get quite complicated as you need to think about different types of objects (arrays, booleans, integers and floating points), how you read each line and symbol etc.

Plus, the fact that you're trying to store values of different types (again, arrays, booleans, integers) into String will give you a headache of serialization of those values when you try to access and use them later.

If you can change how and in which format you get the input, I suggest you to stick to pure JSON for this case and interpret it using any third-party library or extension (first Google search gave me official MS docs and [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)).
Of course, method of storing data will change (that is, probably more than a single Dictionary object) but it definitely will be more organized and easy to use.

Comment: If I use this library, will it be working when I upload the application to my website? I will be loading the .txt files from a database in an online environment so if it will be working properly on a third-party hosting server.

Comment: @UchihaObito in short: it will work, you need to provide all dependencies to the client app but this is entirely unrelated question, I suggest you to get familiar with the field you are trying to work with and do more research on how your set of tools is used for your particular goal; no one will solve all challenges in scope of one SO question.